# How can I accept Microsoft EULA agreement for ttf-mscorefonts-installer in the preseed file?

Tags: preseed

How can I accept Microsoft EULA agreement for ttf-mscorefonts-installer **in a preseeded install** - that is, what `d/i foo/bar` command do I need to add to my preseed file?

Answer (score 3):

The following line works for me when preseeding Xubuntu 12.04 LTS:

```
ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula boolean true
```